# PhpStorm on OSX and intrinsic '/private' directory

Tags: macos, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm on OSX (latest version of both, but that doesn't matter). Due to circumstances beyond my control, the project is located under `/var/projects/` - which, intrinsically, OSX converts to `/private/var/projects/`. My autoloader uses `__DIR__` construct to determine the base location of the classes - and this resolves to `/private/var/projects/myproject/specific/path/autoloader.php`. Consequently, classes are being loaded with paths `/private/var/projects/myproject/path/to/file/class.php`.

As a result, I can't debug them in CLI mode, because the file being loaded is different from the file in the project (i.e. the file in the project doesn't have `/private` in the path) and PhpStorm ignores breakpoints.

Is there any way to tell PhpStorm that `/private/var/projects` is mapped to `/var/projects` - for CLI applications?

If not, what else can I do other than actually opening the project from `/private/var/projects/myproject`?

Comment: Only one suggestion (if you cannot change the project path) -- same as remote debug -- try using path mappings. Alternatively -- try opening this project using "real" `/private/var/projects/myproject` path.

Comment: Path mappings are applicable to a server - I don't have servers, as I am trying to debug a CLI app.  I appreciate that, probably, opening the project from /private/var/projects/myproject will solve the issue, but I'm wondering if there are any other ways.

Comment: Treat it like Remote CLI debug -- there you can use mappings as you will be providing server name (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7906). I'm not sure if this will work if you initiate debug session from IDE (via Debug button) .. so initiate it from PHP side (e.g. `xdebug_debug()` or via xdebug config in php.ini) and on IDE side use "phone handle" icon.

Comment: in `/`, I have a symbolic link that links `var` to `private/var`. Also, as @LazyOne suggests, dont be so literal with client, server, remote, and all sorts of similar terms which convey a general meaning. Xdebug can 'remote-in' to PhpStorm even if they are in the same box. The only issue I have encountered here is the collision between a server port (php-fpm ships with 9000 as default port) and a 'remote client' port (Xdebug also wants 9000). I just use a different port for php-fpm, and voila. Client and server in the same box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no solution that allows to keep the files where they are.  I created another root directory `/opt` and moved projects there.  Now my structure is `/opt/projects/myproject` and everything works as expected.